# Modal window not called after button click

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm making my first website, using Django, python and bootstrap 5, I want a person to click the "submit" button after filling out the form and after that a modal window pops up in which it would say that "everything is OK, your application has been created"

```
<div class="row mt-5 mb-5 p-2">
  <form action="{% url 'feedback_view' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
      <label for="exampleInputName" class="form-label">Ваше Имя</label>
      <input name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" aria-describedby="NameHelp">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
      <label for="exampleInputphone" class="form-label">Ваш Телефон</label>
      <input name="phone" class="form-control" id="exampleInputphone" aria-describedby="NameHelp" placeholder="+7 (918) 000-00-00">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">send</button>
  </form>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">send_btn</button>
```

but for some reason the "send" button does not work, but the "send_btn" button works, which I made to check the problem. all I understand at the moment is what bothers me, type="submit" because in the afternoon there is type="button". How can I solve this problem, given that this is a form submission button? this is the window code:

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="reviews">{{ message }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

it's views.py

```
class FeedBackView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = FeedBackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, settings.MY_INFO, 'now call you!')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, settings.MY_INFO, 'something was wrong')
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Your 'send_btn' is not a form submit. It it a modal initiator. Its job right now is to open the dialog which it does. Your form will be submitted to backend on the press of 'send' as it is a part of <form> tag. Try moving the </form> tag after the second submit button and see what happens. Probably won't fix anything as I see a lot of other problems, but it should give you a start.

Comment: I understand this, I wrote that the send_btn button is made for test .that's why I'm asking if it's possible to somehow make the 'submit' type button act as a modal window call at the same time

Comment: You will have to look into submitting the form through AJAX/[HTMX](https://htmx.org/examples/) for that.

Comment: Another option would be to not submit and call the modal at the same time. Call the modal first, then fill the form and submit.

Comment: thank you, I think so far I have little experience to implement this function

Comment: Just to confirm what you are trying to do: You want to show a modal after form submit to the user that everything was successful?

Comment: Yes, now you understad me

Comment: No need for the button for opening the modal. Post your form, and pass a flag that you can check in front end. If that flag is set, you can show your modal.

Comment: can you tell me more about what you mean